# AWS Glue Error: py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I'm getting this error in AWS Glue:

> "Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o81.getCatalogSource.
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException".

It appears to be erroring when trying to cast to a string. I had cloned an existing job and added the entries in bold. My primary key is a hash from dynamodb, so I can't use that as a primary key. However, the timestamp should always be ascending, so I wanted to tell Glue to use that. The source is DynamoDB, since that MAY make a difference.

My issue is definitely the additional options from the datasource, since if I remove that the job runs fine (albeit without the bookmark). Timestamp shows as a "bigint" in AWS Glue Tables and a "long" in aws glue studio schema. For some reason the error is referencing some conversion to string, but I don't know why the bookmark code in additional options would cause a conversion to string error.

**Modified Code**

```
DataSource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "db", table_name = "table", transformation_ctx = "DataSource0"**, additional_options = {"jobBookmarkKeys":["timestamp"],"jobBookmarkKeysSortOrder":"asc"}**)
```

**Relevant Error**:

```
2021-09-20 13:52:30,848 ERROR [main] glue.ProcessLauncher (Logging.scala:logError(73)): Error from Python:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/nnnnn.py", line 23, in <module>
    DataSource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "db", table_name = "tbl", transformation_ctx = "DataSource0", additional_options = {
    "jobBookmarkKeys": [
        "timestamp"
    ],
    "jobBookmarkKeysSortOrder": "asc"
})
  File "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awsglue/dynamicframe.py", line 625, in from_catalog
    return self._glue_context.create_dynamic_frame_from_catalog(db, table_name, redshift_tmp_dir, transformation_ctx, push_down_predicate, additional_options, catalog_id, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awsglue/context.py", line 177, in create_dynamic_frame_from_catalog
    makeOptions(self._sc, additional_options), catalog_id),
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
**py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o81.getCatalogSource.
: java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.connections.DynamoConnection.$anonfun$broadcastedConf$1(DynamoConnection.scala:49)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.connections.DynamoConnection.$anonfun$broadcastedConf$1$adapted(DynamoConnection.scala:49)**
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashMap1.foreach(HashMap.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:468)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:468)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.connections.DynamoConnection.<init>(DynamoConnection.scala:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.ClassUtils$.newInstanceByName(ClassUtils.scala:59)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.connections.Connection$.apply(Connection.scala:31)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext.getSourceInternal(GlueContext.scala:887)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext.getSource(GlueContext.scala:749)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext.getCatalogSource(GlueContext.scala:396)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext.getCatalogSource(GlueContext.scala:183)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: It is probably trying to convert the timestamp column to a string column in the background so it can use it for the bookmarking function. Why are you using this option though? If you enable Bookmarking in the console for the job, you don't need those additional options.

Comment: If I enable bookmarking in the console for the job... it doesn't work. I have 2 dynamodb source tables. One with 50 rows and the other 35. When I turn bookmarking on within the console and run, every time it runs I get the entire set back. So my table with 50 rows turns into 100 and so on.

Comment: I'm thinking that bookmarks (console only? or script too) do not work on DynamoDB tables, but only on S3 or JDBC

Comment: You are right, they don't seem to work on Dynamo. One possibility would be to use a pipeline consisting out of DynamoDB Streams -> Lambda -> Kinesis Firehose.